# How to get transitive dependencies for a tested bundle for PAX Exam OSGi test runs

Tags: java, maven, osgi, integration-testing, pax-exam

I am using PAX Exam for integration testing. My bundle that I want to test depends on several other bundles. Unfortunately I have not been able to get all of the dependencies pulled in automatically.

Inside my test class I have

```
@Configuration
public Option[] config() {
    return options(
        junitBundles(),
        mavenBundle("io.moquette", "moquette-broker")
    );
}
```

It unfortunately doesn't pull in all of the dependencies for moquette-broker, just the single jar itself.

Is there a way in the test class to specify that it should make all of the dependencies for moquette-broker available for the run? Is there some way to put it in the pom.xml for the exam-maven-plugin? Certainly I didn't see anything in the docs. Or will I be required to enumerate them in the class myself?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get this behavior in plain PAX Exam. You have to list all dependencies in the @Configuration element of you test.

Two ways to make this simpler are using Apache Karaf or bndtools. Both help in very different ways.

If you use karaf as a deployment platform then you can define your application as a feature. In the feature you have to list all bundle dependencies like in pax exam but you can also refer to other such features. So in practice it is much less work. Pax exam can also run such karaf tests based on features. See the [Aries JPA example](https://github.com/apache/aries/blob/trunk/jpa/itests/jpa-container-itest-karaf/src/test/java/org/apache/aries/jpa/itest/karaf/AbstractJPAItest.java#L151-L153).

The other option is to use bndtools there you first define an index. This index can be based on a pom and can also include transitive dependencies. 
Then for your test you define a bndrun file with just the top level bundles to deploy. The resolver will then determine the effective list of runbundles automatically. [See this test run definition of Aries jax-rs whiteboard](https://github.com/apache/aries-jax-rs-whiteboard/blob/master/jax-rs.itests-run/itest.bndrun). Unfortunately this does not work together with pax exam. Bndtools has its own runner. The maven integration of bndtools is also not that stable as you can see in the snapshot versions used. The next version of bndtools (3.4.0) hopefully allows to do this with just release versions.

Comment: Ahh, k, thanks Christian. I was beginning to think that was probably the case. Unfortunate.

I will leave it with Pax Exam for now, but probably move to bndtools once they get their Maven stuff sorted. This is for someone else's project that I wanted to have as an OSGi bundle. For my own project I use Gradle as the buildtool, I will see how well bndtools works within Gradle.

Comment: Karaf looks interesting. I usually use a vanilla Felix for my system, but will definitely consider Karaf to surround my system, or use it for the cloud endpoints.